# obtain granting user and scopes from refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, refresh-token

I have a refresh token in hand, a client_id and a client_secret.

I'd like to determine which end-user the refresh token corresponds to, and/or which scopes.

Is that possible, and, if so, what's the best way to go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly refresh tokens are opaque unreadable values that map to state stored in the Authorization Server.

Some providers may issue refresh tokens as JWTs, in which case you can read the values. Your code will not be portable though, so this is not advised.

**CLIENT**

Usually an OAuth client gets a refresh token from the Authorization Server (AS) after user authentication. Later on the client can try to renew access tokens with it.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

This is the standard component for issuing and renewing refresh tokens and the typical behaviour is like this:

- When a user authenticates, record details of the 'delegation' in a database row
- Typical fields stored are a SHA256 hash of the refresh token, the user and client IDs, and the issued / expiry times of the grant

This information enables the AS to receive and validate [token refresh requests](https://curity.io/resources/learn/refresh-tokens/).

**ISSUING YOUR OWN REFRESH TOKENS**

This should only need to be done if you don't have an AS. In this case follow the AS pattern above. It is recommended instead to use an AS to do it for you though - eg the free edition of Curity from the above link.

Comment: I am the API client.  We have a refresh token stored, but no associated user or scopes. I need to generate a new refresh token and am trying to determine the user/scopes because those need to stay the same.

Comment: I added some notes above on how third party systems handle this